# Basis and subbasis of Tychonoff topology

Tags: general-topology, intuition, product-space

Is there a way  to see intuitively  the basis and subbasis of $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_\alpha,\tau_{\alpha}$ ?

The basis is $\beta_{\pi}=\{\bigcap_{\alpha\in F}\prod_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha):U_\alpha\in\tau_\alpha,F<\infty\}$ and the subbasis is $ S_\pi=\{\prod_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha):U_\alpha \in \tau_\alpha,\alpha\in I)\}$

And another question:  $S_\pi$  the elements  of the set are like $\pi_1,\pi_2,\dots$ and therefore they can be represented as the union.

And the idea generalizes to any kind of set, if a set has the form of $S_\pi,$ then it can be represented as the union, i.e. $\bigcup S_\pi.
$

Am I correct?

Comment: I find this quite intuitive: Tychonoff topology is the smallest topology such that all projections are continuous. Therefore, it must contain every set of the form $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$. But then the topology generated by  the subbasis containing sets of such form is the smallest topology which contains the subbasis, so it must be the Tychonoff topology.

Comment: Another way to describe a member of the base (basis) is $\prod_{a\in I}U_a $such that (i) $U_a\in \tau_a$ for each $a\in I,$ and (ii) $\{a:U_a\ne X_a\}$ is finite. You can  define the Tychonoff product topology as the weakest topology on  $P=\prod_{a\in I}X_a$  such that each projection $\pi_a:P\to X_a$  is continuous.

Comment: My edit was for a typo $\tau_{\pi}$ in the first line, & I removed the brackets, which seem unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see elements of  the product as threads (which may be infinite) consisting of small points, like lines of tightly placed stars at the sky. Then I see the (sub)base sets like bouquets of these threads, bounded, tied at some coordinates, for instance, at $\alpha$-th coordinate by the set $U_\alpha$.

Comment: Is this the only way you see it? I mean is it unique? I wonder under what conditions you were so that you could see such things :D